# Whenever i change the print to 6, it's supposedly print(2(3, none)) but it doesn't

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to code for a factor tree, but my teacher said the output was wrong when I did

```
print(factor(6)),  it should come out like:
(2(3, none) and not just (2, none)
```

how do i fix it?

```
def factor(x):
i = 2
while x > i:
        if x % i == 0 and x != i:            
            if x == i:
                return i
            return i, factor(x/i)
        else:
            i+= 1 
print(factor(6))
```

Comment: Should there be an extra closing parenthesis in the expected output? One of the opening parentheses doesn't have a closing one.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
def factor(x,i=2):
  while x > i:
        if x % i == 0 and x != i:            
            if x == i:
                return i
            return i,factor(x,i+1)
        else:
            i+= 1 
print(factor(6))
```

[Demo](https://onecompiler.com/python/3y84bz7wf)